# How to only show the full url on HTML 5

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

How do you change so only the full url is shown, example:

Before: https://stackoverflow.com/anotherlink#script

How I want it: https://stackoverflow.com/

Edit: sorry for being unclear I meant Adress bar

Comment: Please try to make your question way more clear. I'm not able to figure out what you're actually asking and others won't either.

Comment: hm I shown you a example: Before and after, don't know how to make it any more clear

Comment: So you want the URL address bar to always say `http://example.com/` while you navigate to all kinds of links on your site?

Comment: Only the full url is shown WHERE? In the location bar? In a link on a Webpage?

Comment: oh sorry, got it. On the adress bar ofcourse.
Yes exactly Jon Lin.

Comment: Maybe using $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST, $_SESSION ? But I don't know I really get what you are trying to do. You mean something like Opera does with it's address bar (showing only the host).

Comment: Use AJAX loading of content.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel as far as it regards a small webpage or only a few selected pages – as soon as it grows bigger I would prefer a frameset (though I don't like them personally), as it just becomes an huge work/time overhead; You need to render each page in JS after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a frame set containing only a single frame.

Your frameset index.html can't be HTML5 - it has to be XHTML1 or HTML4 - but that's completely compatible with HTML5 pages in the frame itself.